# HtmlAgilityPack xPath scraping

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am trying to scrape this site
http://www.gotickets.com/calendar.php?Display=Daily&Date=2013-03-12&EventTypeID=2&EventID=0&GenreID=159&VenueID=0&MarketAreaID=0

This is what interests me

The data is heirarchly organized as follows

```
<div class="clr dayItem">
 <div class="clr genreHeader">Alternative Rock</div>
 <div class="clr genreEvents">
  <div class="clr dayEvent">
   <a href="/concert/muse/houston_1339329.php" title="7:00 PM Muse - Toyota Center - TX">Muse - Toyota Center - TX - 7:00 PM
   </a>
 </div>
 <div class="clr dayEvent">
  <a href="/concert/matchbox_20/pooler_1347335.php" title="7:30 PM Matchbox 20 - Johnny Mercer Theatre">Matchbox 20 - Johnny Mercer Theatre - 7:30 PM
  </a>
</div>

etc...
  </div>
 </div>
```

So Basically
the page is divided into two columns
each column has DayItems
which include the genere
and the dayEvents with the hrefs

I have been trying to get the data out, but i am completely new to xpath, and have been scraping with Regex until today

the Regex is getting cumbersome and too complicated, so I have opted for xPath

to get the DayItems I use:

```
 var cl = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' dayItem ')]");

 foreach (var item in cl.Where(x=> x.Attributes.Any(p=>p.Value == "clr dayItem" && p.OriginalName=="class")))
      {

            /// THIS LINE FAILS
          var genre = item.SelectSingleNode("//.[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' genre ')]");


          Console.WriteLine(item.Name);

          foreach (var attr in item.Attributes.Select(x => x.OriginalName + ".." + x.Value))
          {


              Console.WriteLine(attr);
          }
      }
```

Comment: So what do you need exactly? the content of all A elements in clr dayEvent DIVs elements?

Comment: I need all event data, so i can create a csv file, to pivot over
I have attached a working sample, but I would still appreciate a chance to learn how to do this completely and only in xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my working code, it's not as clean as I would like, but this is just a data finding expedition. i will never use this software again
I would appreciate someone fixing my code to make it more efficient and better depending on xpath

```
string html = client.DownloadString("http://www.gotickets.com/calendar.php?Display=Daily&EventTypeID=1&EventID=0&GenreID=159&VenueID=0&MarketAreaID=0" + "&Date=" + MakeDate);


      List<Event> events = new List<Event>();

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
      document.LoadHtml(html);

      var cl = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' dayItem ')]");

      foreach (var item in cl)
      {

          var genre_text = item.InnerText.Replace("\t\t", "").Replace("\t\t\t\t", "").Replace("\t\t\t", "").Replace("\t\t", "").Replace("\t", "");

          var lines = genre_text.Split(new string[] {"\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x=>  WebUtility.HtmlDecode(x)).ToArray();

          var genre = lines.Take(1).First();

          events.AddRange(lines.Skip(1).Select(f =>


              new Event(f, f.Split(new string[] { "-" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries), genre, this.Date)

              ));


      }
```

the Event class is just a container

```
public class Event
{
    private string OriginalString;
    private string[] p;

    public Event(string originalString, string[] parts, string genre, DateTime date)
    {
        this.OriginalString = originalString;
        this.p = parts;
        this.Genre = genre;
        this.Date = date;
        analyze(parts);
    }
 public override string ToString()
    {
        string pattern = "{0},{1},{2},{3}";
        var s = string.Format(pattern, this.Date.ToString("MMM"), this.Genre, this.Location, this.Performer);
        return s;

    }

    private void analyze(string[] parts)
    {
        if (parts.Length < 3)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Length < 3 ==> " + parts.Length);
        }

        if (parts.Length > 3)
        {
            this.Performer = parts[0].Trim();
            this.Location = parts[1].Trim() + "-" + parts[2].Trim();

        }
        else
        {
            this.Performer = parts[0].Trim();
            this.Location = parts[1].Trim();

        }

    }

    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public string Performer { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

It works but it's UGLYYY

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do this quite easily with XPATH. It's easy because the document is well structured and has meaningful CLASS attributes.

```
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.gotickets.com/calendar.php?Display=Daily&Date=2013-03-12&EventTypeID=2&EventID=0&GenreID=159&VenueID=0&MarketAreaID=0");

        foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='clr dayEvent']"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Event: " + node.InnerText);

            HtmlNode genre = node.SelectSingleNode("../../div[@class='clr genreHeader']");
            Console.WriteLine(" Genre:" + HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(genre.InnerText));
        }
```

You can adapt this to your Event class. Inside the event text, it's not HTML so you have to parse it like you do in your Event code.

You can learn XPATH here: [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/)

Comment: what i was missing was the  .. /..  syntax
also i tried //div[@class=\"clr dayEvent\"]  but for some  reason it returned empty data.  so i had to hack it like i did with the contains.  

my two issues were
how to get all single genre events and how to query inside a genre result without xpath looking in other document hierarchies.